# Magento 2 how to have product Advanced Inventory as store level

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-attribute, multistore, inventory

How to set product Advanced Inventory as store level. I need this store level for each product

I have two stored one is retail and wholesale, How can I set quantity increment only with wholesale So that user select bulk Quantity.

[image]

Comment: select product at store level and then change advanced inventory.

Comment: If i change it for retail it changes for wholesale and vice versa. its not taking input as store level since its Global.

Comment: oh you may check use system values check box and then check it once.

Comment: Where can I find the system checkbox, I am not getting you Sorry.

Comment: use config settings check box, under qty box

Comment: Checking this only sets the global configuration value to the field its dint do any changes with the Store level configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84195/discussion-between-fernandus-and-suresh-vagvala).